# Raw menu data in block.tpl.php

Tags: 7, routes, blocks

I need to access the raw menu data in a menu block, but `$content` only stores the rendered markup. How can I gain access to this object from within the `block--sidebar_second.tpl.php` file?

I've looked into creating a View but I couldn't figure out how to select menu nodes. Either solution will work for me...

Here is the output of the `$block` object:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [bid] => 196
    [module] => menu_block
    [delta] => 7
    [theme] => theme-name
    [status] => 1
    [weight] => 0
    [region] => sidebar_second
    [custom] => 0
    [visibility] => 0
    [pages] => 
    [title] => Services Menu
    [cache] => -1
    [subject_array] => Array
        (
            [#markup] => Services
        )

    [subject] => Services
    [last_in_region] => 1
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the menu array structure in your block theme template, you need to implement a [`template_preprocess_block()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21block%21block.module/function/template_preprocess_block/7) in your theme's **template.php**:

```
//@TODO: replace MYTHEME with your theme name
function MYTHEME_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
  //Only add on sidebar_second region
  if($variables['block']->region == 'sidebar_second') {
    //Replace "my-menu" with the machine name of your menu
    $variables['menu'] = menu_tree_all_data('my-menu');
  }
}
//after flushing caches $menu should be available in your block template.
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are using [Menu block](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_block) module, and you would have already successfully placed the menu-tree in your region. If your desire is to access raw menu data from a menu block, just use TEMPLATE_preprocess_block(&$variables).

$variables['content'] is rendered.
**$variables['elements']['#content']** is raw.